# Getting Access Denied Exception while trying to Open Socket In Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, exception

I am getting Access Denied exception while trying to open a socket.
My connect function is as shown.

```
internal void Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                //AccessPolicy = new SocketClientAccessPolicyProtocol();


                args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();


                args.UserToken = socket;
                args.RemoteEndPoint = endPoint;
                args.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnConnect);

                **isConnected = socket.ConnectAsync(args);**
                //autoEvent.WaitOne();

                if (args.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
                    throw new SocketException((int)args.SocketError);
                if(isConnected)
                global::System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Connected");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                global::System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The function ConnectAsync however is executing fine as isConnected is coming true but socket is not getting connected.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If your problem is solved, please accept the best answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

http://drdobbs.com/windows/208403238

> Looking through the code you'll see that it uses the TcpListener class to listen for incoming client connections. Once a client connects the code checks the request for the following value: `<policy-file-request/>`
>
> Silverlight automatically sends this text to the policy file socket once it connects. If the request contains the proper value the code writes the contents of the client access policy back to the client stream (see the OnReceiveComplete() method). Once the policy file is received, Silverlight parses it, checks that it allows access to the desired port, and then accepts or **rejects the socket call that the application is trying to make**.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Silverlight in the browser, you need a socket policy server in the mix. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx for details.